# Total surface area of hemispherical shell

Tags: calculus, geometry

I need to find the area of a hollow hemisphere (hemispherical shell) using the integration formula for surface area. How should I go about it?

Comment: What have you tried?  How does this relate to the well-known formula for the area of a sphere?  The area of an annulus (ring)?

Comment: Do you know how to find the area of a surface of revolution? Hint: Consider the graphs of the equations for two hemispheres of radius $r$ and $R$, $y_1=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and $y_2=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, in the first quadrant (so $x\ge0$), with $r<R$.

Answer (score 1):

Does this figure clarify the matter?

[image]